# Azure How can I call Azure Private Endpoint (Azure Private Link service) by private IP inside of VNET

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network, azure-private-dns

I created VNET in Azure. I put in one subset Azure Private Link which calls Azure Function outside of the VNET and in another one Virtual machine. 
 When I tried to call private endpoint by private IP I got a 400 exception. And if I try to ping private IP from the VM it doest work. 
But by URL it works well.
 Is it any way to call it by IP?

Comment: What's the specific URL that works? Do you use private link between Azure function on app service and Azure VM?

Comment: When you create an Azure Private link it creates DNS which is URL to private IP which is Azure Network interface. For me, it is the link to the Azure Function App

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also face the same scenario and it seems it's expected behavior.

First of all, instead of **Ping** tool(using ICMP protocol) inside Azure VM, you could use **[PsPing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psping)** tool(using TCP protocol) to test the networking connectivity.

[image]

It indicates the Azure function with port 443 with private endpoint is open and should be abled to accepted connection.

Azure function on Azure app service plan is multi-tenant, the same IP address is used for many web apps. Thus, we can not call each instance with it's IP address via the web browser. If you would like to call it with private IP, as a workaround, you could call it by [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) tool with adding your azure function host as the picture displayed.

[image]